# How to get JSON data from api in android studio

Tags: json

I am developing android app for my client, but the data he wants is from api. lets take this as sample url

curl -X GET "https://zbc.zbcredio.co.tz/api/zbc/friends/aggregators/stations?page=<PAGE_NR>&hitsPerPage=<HITS_PER_PAGE>" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "x-zbc-api-key: <API_KEY>"

here is sample api-key frome him 8jruy76h5-230f-76te-yewrt-987gkjksdnfd

i am confused with page=<> & hitPerPafe =<>
and other staff. i am using rest api.
someone help me

i am totally confused.
i am doing nothing now, i have set volley, and everything, just want to fetch data.